# Uninstalling SQL Server 2012

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, uninstallation

I need to uninstall SQL Server 2012 on computer with Windows Server 2008, but I need to leave all existing databases. In other words, I need to remove SQL Server, but without deleting all data. How could I manage that? Also, where should be all databases phisically(.mdf files)?

Comment: take a `backup` -->`uninstall`-->`reinstall`-->`recover`

Comment: Can't - license ended. Copying all databases phisically would work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have or can take backups then you could:

1. Shut down your database instance using SQL Server Configuration
   Manager.
2. Find where your database files are located and copy these safely
   somewhere.
3. At this point you could try mounting these on an alternative (test) SQL
   Server (using the SQL Server 'Attach Database'). This will give you
   confidence that the re-install will work on whatever SQL Version you
   are planning to move them to.
4. Then as others have stated, uninstall SQL Server
5. Reinstall
6. Re-attach

NOTE - this does not preserve instance level security, so you will need to script out any special security settings for these databases and then re-import it back in (See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58772/how-to-export-all-the-security-related-information-from-a-sql-server-database).

Answer (score 0):

Detach Databases ,keep Database files , run controlpanel program and feature and unistall it.